# reduce the font size while printing using OPOS printer for receipt

Tags: c#, .net, point-of-sale, epson, opos

How can we reduce the size of text/font while printing using an OPOS printer?
I am using an Epson printer and the following softare components for making this work.

- OPOS ADK for .Net
- Microsoft POS for .Net

command used for printing a line is

```
m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "\u001b|cA" + "noob is printing"+ "\n");
```

Is ther any escape charater for reducing the font size? 
RecLineChars is set as 42.

Answer (score 2):

We use the following:

```
// Scale the font to OPOS (1 to 4)
int fontSize = (int)Math.Round((format.FontSize.Value - 5) / 5.0);
if (fontSize < 1)
    fontSize = 1;
if (fontSize > 4)
    fontSize = 4;
_printerText += string.Format("\x1B|{0}C", fontSize);
```

Comment: i know this setting.. But what i wanted to know is if we can choose a font size less than 1. ie, 0.5 or something..

Comment: i dont think that it is possible. If you want something like that you should print via graphics.

Comment: @TutuGeorge have you found the solution for this?